# Why ServiceMix with jetty and hawtio component try to connect livepassdl.conviva.com on port 443

Tags: java, jetty, hawtio, apache-servicemix

I'm using service mix version 5.4.0 with hawtio enabled, recently I saw on the log the following trace:

****: Last reset cause - Power On Resetction           | [64][org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server][8. 1.15.v20140411] | [] **livepassdl.conviva.com:443** java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1         at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1938)[:1.6.0_07]         at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.spi.model.ServerModel.matchPathToContext(ServerModel.java:335)[71:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-s pi:3.1.2]         at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.spi.model.ServerModel.matchPathToContext(ServerModel.java:290)[71:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-s pi:3.1.2]         at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.JettyServerHandlerCollection.handle(JettyServerHandlerCollection.java:62)[73:o rg.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:3.1.2]         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)[64:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-al l-server:8.1.15.v20140411]         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)[64:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v2014041 1]         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)[64:org.eclipse.jetty.agg regate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:971)[64:org.eclipse.jetty.ag gregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1033)[64:org. eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]         at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:644)[64:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15 .v20140411]         at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)[64:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8 .1.15.v20140411]         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)[64:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-a ll-server:8.1.15.v20140411]         at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:696)[64:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.je tty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]         at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:53)[64:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jett y-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]         at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)[64:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-a ll-server:8.1.15.v20140411]         at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)[64:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-al l-server:8.1.15.v20140411]         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)[:1.6.0_07]****

I'm trying to find which file have the string  "**livepassdl**" but I din't have success with the following command on apache-servicemix-5.4.0 directory

*find ./ -type f | xargs grep "livepassdl"*

only I had found in ./data/log/servicemix.log

Why Servicemix or hawtio or jetty try to connect to **livepassdl.conviva.com:443**?
 and how can I disable this feature?

Comment: This is not a software development question.  This question would be better suited for serverfault.com

Comment: From the stacktrace I rather read it differently, something or someone is trying to connect to livepassdl.onviva.com:443 through your sevicemix instance

Comment: Yes its surely not hawtio that does something like that. Maybe you have some apps deployed that does this.